# How to pass selected resource absolute path as a program argument in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Does anybody here know how to pass the selected resource path as an argument to "Run Configuration" in Intellij?

I have used Eclipse before and eclipse has this nice little option where you can pass ${selected_resource_loc} as the program argument and it takes the resource location, but I could not find an equivalent option to use in Intellij.

Comment: When you do run configuration that time you have an option option for VM arguments and environment variables as well ...

Comment: But it doesnt allow providing something similar to {selected_resource_loc} from eclipse.

Comment: What I am looking for is to be able to run from any resource and still be able to pass the resource I have selected, instead of some hardcoded option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may probably want to start your build process as an external tool (configured in "Settings">"External Tools"). Have the tool show in Project views and use $FileDir$ as an argument or working directory. Now you should be able to right-click a module/project/directory and start your process.

[image: External Tools pop up]

As far as I'm aware of, there is no direct equivalent in IntelliJ. You may set up different Environmental Variables in the Run Configurations within Intellij, but you'll have to define separate run configurations for each individual module.

You can open a [feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FIDEA) request in their issue tracker, and maybe they'll implement it in a future release.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the closest to getting this resolved. And as you suggested, I will open a feature request.